# Javascript: creating divs

Tags: javascript, object, dom, methods, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make javascript application where a user can enter the kind of cookie she/he wants to make, and then select the amount of cookies they want. Once the user makes this selection and presses the "bake" button, the cookies appear randomly in the page. I had an assignment once where I had to generate random divs on a page, and it kind of gave me the idea for this, which is just for fun and practice.

My problem is that I want the user to be able to get unique information about the cookies he/she creates by clicking on them, and I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)
Click Event is not defined properly :

```
 aCookie.onlclick = cookie.display(); 

 // typing error onlclick

 // cookie.display() actually it call display function, doesn't give  reference
```

change to :

```
  aCookie.onclick = cookie.display;
```

(2)
set id "kind" to input box

(3)
Current code set properties (id,kind,x,y) to instance of Cookie, not to element.
Change code so that, the element is a parameter & set properties to it.

```
//pass element to set properties
function Cookie(elem,id, kind, x, y) {

    elem.id = id;
    elem.kind = kind;
    elem.x = x;
    elem.y = y;

    this.display = function () {
        alert("Cookie number: " + this.id + "; is a: " + this.kind + "; cookie : " +
            " and it is situated on coordinates ;  " + this.y + " and " + this.x + " on the cookie pan");
    }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/CzgLj/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I still can't get it to work though. What do you mean by id="kind" is not set to input[type="text"]?

Comment: kind id you didnt give that id to the input tag, 
input tag you use to get cookie type , ex. oreo

Comment: Hi, aslan. Thanks for the help. The problem is that when I click one of the generated cookies on the screen, the alert box displays this:     Cookie number: ; is a: undefined; cookie :  and it is situated on coordinates ;  undefined and undefined on the cookie pan. and I want the alert box to display the kind, id number and x and y coordinates of each cookie that is clicked. Thanks though for the help.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see that issue : i fixed it, please check ::http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/CzgLj/